# How do I pass a mutable reference to a method on an object that belongs to that reference?

Tags: rust

I have a struct instance A that belongs to a struct instance B.  I will need to do some processing on this data by calling the parent.

```
struct A {
    val : u8
}

struct B {
    data : u8,
    a : A
}

impl A {
    pub fn process(&mut self, b : &mut B) {
        println!("Processing {} - {}", b.data, self.val);
        //do stuff with val and data...
    }
}

impl B {
    pub fn process(&mut self) {
        self.a.process(self);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut b = B {
        data : 0,
        a : A {
            val : 3
        }
    };

    b.process();
}
```

When I try to call b.process(), I'm getting the following failure:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `self.a` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:47:9
   |
47 |         self.a.process(self);
   |         ^^^^^^^-------^----^
   |         |      |       |
   |         |      |       first mutable borrow occurs here
   |         |      first borrow later used by call
   |         second mutable borrow occurs here

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:47:24
   |
47 |         self.a.process(self);
   |         ---------------^^^^-
   |         |      |       |
   |         |      |       second mutable borrow occurs here
   |         |      first borrow later used by call
   |         first mutable borrow occurs here
```

All of this works fine when mutable references aren't needed.

So my question is, what's the right way to do this when I need this type of relationship between the two structs?

Comment: Could you pass just the `&mut B` and access the `A` through its field?

Comment: I can do it that way, making A::process static.  I'm not sure if that's really the right way to do this though.  I guess coming from an OOP world it seems strange to do it this way.

Comment: From an OOP perspective, it doesn't make sense to me that this method is defined for A rather than for B. It needs both, but a B is sufficient because the B has the A. In OOP it would also be desirable to not have a class A make use of class B, when class B already has a dependency on class A, as that makes a circular dependency.

Comment: Besides all this, Rust is not OO. Contrary to *some* OO languages, functions can exist on their own in Rust, and in fact methods are just syntactic sugar for associated functions (what you called static methods), which in turn are just regular functions put into a namespace (the only exception being when you explicitly ask for dynamic dispatch, which is not the case here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rust you can either have a single mutable reference or multiple immutable references, or, put differently: single writer / multiple readers.

```rust
    let mut a = 0; // Only mutable variables can be written to
    let a1 = &a;
    let a2 = &a; // Readers can be many
    // This is an error:
    let a3 = &mut a; // You cannot write to `a` while it is borrowed for reading

    print!("{} {} {}", a1, a2, a3)
```

```rust
    let mut a = 0;
    let a1 = &mut a; // You can have a single writer

    // This is an error:
    let a2 = &mut a; // But there can be only one
    // This is also an error:
    let a3 = &a; // You cannot read while `a` can be written to

    print!("{} {} {}", a1, a2, a3)
```

Following this logic we can make some observations on the code

```rust
impl A {
    // this implies that both self and B can change
    pub fn process(&mut self, b: &mut B) {
        println!("Processing {} - {}", b.data, self.val);
        //do stuff with val and data...
    }

    pub fn process_changes_a(&mut self, b: &B) {
        println!("Processing {} - {}", b.data, self.val);
    }

    pub fn process_changes_b(&self, b: &mut B) {
        println!("Processing {} - {}", b.data, self.val);
    }
}

impl B {
    pub fn process(&mut self) {
        // it's possible to use clones to work around this
        // however it's probably better to refactor the logic

        // let's see what happens when using clones
        let mut tmp_self = self.clone();
        let mut tmp_a = self.a.clone();

        // this can modify both self.a and tmp_self
        self.a.process(&mut tmp_self);
        // now self and tmp_self could be different

        // does self need to have the value of the &mut B?
        // note: this clone is only necessary for
        // the other examples to compile
        *self = tmp_self.clone();

        // or does only self.a need to change?
        tmp_a.process(self);
        self.a = tmp_a;

        // or should the original self.a stay the same?
        self.data = tmp_self.data;
    }

    pub fn process_changes_a(&mut self) {
        // you still need a clone of self.a
        // otherwise A::process_changes_a could
        // modify a through self while reading b.a
        let mut tmp_a = self.a.clone();
        tmp_a.process_changes_a(self);
        self.a = tmp_a;
    }

    pub fn process_changes_b(&mut self) {
        // you still need a clone of self.a
        // otherwise A::process_changes_b could
        // modify a through b.a while reading self
        let tmp_a = self.a.clone();
        tmp_a.process_changes_b(self);
    }

    pub fn process_on_self(&mut self) {
        // if you need to modify both self and self.a
        // it might be best to have the method directly on B
        println!("Processing {} - {}", self.data, self.a.val);
    }
}
```

The problem really comes from the fact that `A::process(&mut self, b: &mut B)` doesn't know that both `self` and `b.a` reference the same value when called from `B` and expects them to be different. You can make it work by using clones or copies, however it is probably unnecessary.

Personally, I'd probably try to move the logic of `process()` entirely to B. In your example A depends on B, but also B depends on A. This would make it so that only B depends on A, which makes things simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can't that's against Rusts aliasing rules, you'd have two mutable references to the `A` one direct and one indirectly through `B`. If you really wanted to you could use interior mutability (`RefCell`, `Mutex`, ...) but as kaya3 pointed out your suggested implementation seems rather strange even from an OO viewpoint. If it needs a `B` anyways, I'd just implement it on `B` diretly without the indirection.